# Remove focus rectangle on M6 Mark II during clean HDMI out to Elgato Cam Link with autofocus enabled?

Tags: canon, canon-m

I have a Canon M6 Mark II camera, and recently purchased an Elgato Cam Link so I can use it as a very high quality webcam during social distancing. I got it working pretty quickly, however even with "clean" HDMI output it still displays the autofocus rectangle - regardless of focus setting. I would prefer autofocus but can live with manual focus, but even when set to MF, it still displays the rectangle.

I've tried the following (with result):

- Switching physical body switch from AF to MF (removes AF rectangle from live view, but it still appears on my PC)
- Disabling Movie Servo AF in menu options (greys out AF rectangle on live view and Servo AF icon not displayed)
- Disabling Movie Servo AF temporarily in live view (same as disabling in menu except the icon is still there)
- The same as above but in FHD instead of 4k (no difference)

This is frustrating since nothing about displaying the AF rectangle is "clean" IMO. This usage was not anticipated prior to buying the camera as I've only done stills, no use of any kind of video before. If relevant, I'm using the Canon 22mm EF-M lens.

I've seen a variety of recommendations online for cameras from the same family (M50, M100, M6 I) and not many specifically regarding the M6 II. They either state you cant remove the box, or switching to MF will remove it, neither of which appear to be the case unless there's some way to switch to MF that I haven't tried yet.

This isn't super important to me but wanted to ask in case there is actually a solution and for clearer SEO than the bunch of antiquated camera forums I browsed through trying to find a solution earlier.

Comment: Have you try to activate face detection? According to some sources this help with some Canon cameras

Comment: I did try toggling that as well, neglected to list it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I am very dumb. I was using the Windows Camera app to view the image from my camera. It has its own face focus square thing that does NOT get rendered in other applications; it was not the in-camera autofocus square being shown, though it does show in the live view on the camera itself. So, it is a clean HDMI out.